# jsp substitution in tiles.xml

Tags: tiles, tiles2, apache-tiles

I was looking at the Travel demo project and noticed that in the tiles.xml under hotel that there was the following:

```
    <definition name="hotels/*" extends="standardLayout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/hotels/{1}.jsp" />
</definition>
```

From what I can see this allows the controller to return something like "hotels/list", the "list" is then mapped into {1} and /WEB-INF/views/hotels/{1}.jsp becomes

```
    /WEB-INF/views/hotels/list.jsp
```

I was looking through the apache-tiles documentation but couldn't find any mention of it or what versions it applied to.

Can someone point me to where it is referenced in the docs, or anyplace else? I'd like to learn a little more.

Comment: Okay found it. I forgot to put "wildcard" in my google search. An example is here: http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/wildcard.html